# Get a hold of an item preceeding the dropped item in jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>


$('ul').sortable();
```

Let's say, I'm moving around li #6.  If I place it between #1 and #2, I need to get a hold of li #1.  If I place it between #3 and #4, I need to get a hold of li #3.  How would I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just query it with `$(this).prev()` in the dropped callback?

Comment: @ohcibi how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would select this item with `prev()` in the `stop` callback:

```
$('ul').sortable({
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.prev().html());
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TprfC/1/

Comment: I suppose, I could do that in the "receive" callback as well, correct?